# ti.ntlm module: not working when updated to titanium 5.0 sdk

Tags: android, sharepoint, networking, appcelerator

I have been using ti.ntlm module in my android project for accessing the SharePoint services we have. So far project was running on 3.5.2 titanium sdk. But we were asked to move the project to 5.0 sdk. For using the module we use Titanium.Network.HTTPClient.addAuthFactory api as stated in the example.

if (Ti.Platform.osname == 'android') {

```
var Ntlm = require('ti.ntlm');
client.addAuthFactory(Ntlm.getAuthScheme(), Ntlm.getAuthFactory());
```

}
//client is HTTPClient object.

Now the problem is since we are moving to 5.0 sdk, in this sdk the above mentioned api is removed completely. So the project throws error when run.

We would like to know the solution for this issue. Any new api we should use instead of addAuthFactory? Anyone facing the same issue?

Please do reply to the query. It is a very important module in my project.